# Understanding This Crash Report

Tags: ios, iphone, crash-reports

I just received this crash report for my app from Flurry Analytics. But I don't know how to read this. It seems like there's no enough information to really tell what or where is this crash.

**Could any of you guys help understand this report?**

Thanks!

***REPORT:***

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x19b7971e0 ___pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x19b706c00 _abort + 140
2   libc++abi.dylib                     0x19a4bd3f4 ___cxa_bad_cast + 0
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x19a4d9e98  + 0
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x19ae34264  + 124
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x19a4d6f44  + 16
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x19a4d6b10 ___cxa_rethrow + 144
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x19ae3413c _objc_exception_rethrow + 44
8   CoreFoundation                      0x1862a9328 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
9   GraphicsServices                    0x1914200cc _GSEventRunModal + 180
10  UIKit                               0x18ba96df8 _UIApplicationMain + 204
11  MYAPP                               0x1000ffe24 main + 96 (main.m:21)
12  libdyld.dylib                       0x19b6768b8  + 4
```

Comment: This does not look like the full error -- did you copy and paste the whole error report?

Comment: The crash is caused by an unhandled exception and the report is missing the last exception backtrace and also the exception message. Without that it is impossible to say what is going on.